# select distinct values in an array originating from a web api with angled

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a web api (.NET Core 3.1) that returns a json like the following:

```
[
    {
        "counterparty": "Santander",
        "tradeDate": "2020-05-23T10:03:12",
        "isin": "DOL110",
        "typology": 0
    },
    {
        "counterparty": "Jordan Banks",
        "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T11:23:22",
        "isin": "LIT250",
        "typology": 0
    },
    {
        "counterparty": "Santander",
        "tradeDate": "2020-06-11T11:24:08",
        "isin": "LIT300",
        "typology": 0
    }
]
```

I consume this web api with the component and angular service below. So far, I return the `counterparty` field of all objects.

operations.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OperationsService } from "./operations.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-operations',
  templateUrl: './operations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operations.component.css']
})
export class OperationsComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;

  constructor(private operationsService: OperationsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadOperations();
  }

  loadOperations() {
    return this.operationsService.getOperations().subscribe(source => this.data = source);
  }
}
```

operations.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  <div>{{item.counterparty}}</div>
</div>
```

operations.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class OperationsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getOperations() {
    return this.http.get("https://localhost:44329/api/operations");
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './user/login/login.component';
import { OperationsComponent } from './operations/operations/operations.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    OperationsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'api/operations', component: OperationsComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

what i need now is to apply a filter in the counterparty field to return only the distinct values, that is, without repetitions of equal values. I'm trying with ng-repeat, but i have the error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   The pipe 'unique' could not be found ("]item of data | unique: item.counterparty">
>     {{item.counterparty}}
>   
>   ")

So, how can I get the distinct values of the array? Can I do it only in component.html or do I also have to change component.ts?

Comment: You must have forgottten to include some code because the error doesnt seems related to what you are showing. And yes you should to it in the ts.

Comment: Do you have custome pipe as unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's best to make your this.data array unique in component.ts, then just display it in component.html.

You can use another function with promise to make data array unique, based on 'counterparty'.

```
 // make data array unique
codeToMakeItUnique = dataArr => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const UniArr = []
        const map = new Map()
        for (const item of dataArr) {
            if (!map.has(item.counterparty)) {
                map.set(item.counterparty, true) // set any value to Map
                UniArr.push(item)
            }
        }
        resolve(UniArr)
    })
}
```

so altogether your component.ts will look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OperationsService } from "./operations.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-operations',
    templateUrl: './operations.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./operations.component.css']
})
export class OperationsComponent implements OnInit {

    data: any;

    constructor(private operationsService: OperationsService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadOperations();
    }

    loadOperations() {
        return this.operationsService.getOperations().subscribe(async source => {
            this.data = await this.codeToMakeItUnique(source)
        });

        // make data array unique
        codeToMakeItUnique = dataArr => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const UniArr = []
                const map = new Map()
                for (const item of dataArr) {
                    if (!map.has(item.counterparty)) {
                        map.set(item.counterparty, true) // set any value to Map
                        UniArr.push(item)
                    }
                }
                resolve(UniArr)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

In your component.html you can simply call your data array itself

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  <div>{{item.counterparty}}</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The question isnt clear but if you want to remove duplicated value from your array, cast it as a set then back to an array. That is if the array doesnt contains complex objects

```
  loadOperations() {
    return this.operationsService.getOperations().subscribe(source => this.data = Array.from(new Set(source.map((item: any) => item.counterparty))));
  }
```

This is going to give you `[ "Santander", "Jordan Banks" ]`

Comment: In the field counterparty, I havee 3 registers in the database: "Santander", "Jordan Banks", "Santander". I want to apply a filter that returns only unique values for the counterparty, therefore, or the expected result of this serious filter: "Snatander", "Jordan Banks". Was I clearer?

Comment: So what is the expected result? just: ['Santander', 'Jordan Banks']?

Comment: Yes...eliminate repeated counterparts.